# Joomla 2.5 Component - Store date/time, display on different timezones

Tags: mysql, datetime, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

Developing a component for Joomla v2.5, I'm using a table with a mysql timestamp column.

One of the component's settings is the "Timezone". I don't want to use server timezone, as code will run on different servers/timezones and I want to be indepedent. So the idea is to store timestamps in mysql, and display the correct date/time according to the component's parameter. The main drawback is the timezone that mysql server uses, that make the whole situation complicated. So, is there a way to store current timestamp in an universal format in MySQL and display it in the correct way?

The ultimate goal is for the component to be able to display the correct date/time based on the component's parameter, eg. user changes the parameter on the fly, no modification on the database take place, only on the "View"

In order to display the date in the correct timezone I use this:

```
JHtml::date($date_from_mysql , 'd/m/Y H:i:s', $my_component_timezone_parameter)
```

Please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 3):

try

```
jimport ('joomla.utilities.date');
$date = new JDate($mydate);
$curdate = $date->toFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S');
```

for timezone settings
try [http://docs.joomla.org/JDate::setTimezone/1.6](http://docs.joomla.org/JDate%3a%3asetTimezone/1.6)

http://www.webamoeba.co.uk/site/index.php/articles-joomla-date-time

Answer (score 0):

or try to override the store method in your table class:

```
public function store($updateNulls = false)
{
    // get date
    $date = JFactory::getDate();

    // set variable for timestamp
    $this->myDate = $date->toMySQL();

    return parent::store($updateNulls);
}
```

Comment: In Joomla 3.x it should be `$date->toSql()` instead of  `$date->toMySQL()`